# Report Manager Deployment Connection String

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

Replications Steps

I have deploy a report onto Report Manager 2012 and can't seem to run it . It gives me the following error. I checked the connection the the datasource in Report manager and works ok.
I have also set up an execution account on Reporting Services configuration manager.

Error

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   Cannot create a connection to data source 'DataSource1'.
>   (rsErrorOpeningConnection) The ConnectionString property has not been
>   initialized.

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

The execution account is my windows nt account . The datasoource is on another server. Reports works fine in Sql Server data tools 2012.

Comment: Depending on how you create the data source in the report project will affect where the data source is located on the report server.  If it is not shared, it will be using a data source embedded data source which will be located with the report and not in the data sources folder.  I would check where the connection is on the properties of the report and make sure that is working properly.

Comment: Created data source as shared data source and saved with use this username and password. Data source in located in its own folder( data Sources) in Report Manager and Report in its own folder( Report Temple). Not sure about last point on checking the properties of the report as I cant see anyone for data sources .

Comment: Solved . Made the datasources and datasets shared and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

Solved . Made the datasources and datasets shared and it now works.